# How to extract the text values of a given attribute using Xpath?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to extract the text within the content attribute using X path.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="football,cricket,Rugby,Volleyball">
```

I want to select only "football,cricket,Rugby,Volleyball"

I'm using C#, htmlagilitypack.

this is how I supposed to do this.but it did not work.

```
private void scrapBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = urlTextBox.Text;
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);


               try
            {
                var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title/text()");
                var node1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/meta[@name='DESCRIPTION']/@content");

                try
                {
                    label4.Text = "Title:";
                    label4.Text += "\t"+node.Name.ToUpper() + ": " + node.OuterHtml;
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(url + "does not contain <Title>", "Oppz, Sorry");
                }

                try
                {
                    label4.Text += "\nMeta Keywords:";
                    label4.Text += "\n\t" + node1.Name.ToUpper() + ": " + node1.OuterHtml;
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(url + "does not contain <meta='Keywords'>", "Oppz, Sorry");
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, "Oppz, Sorry");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error do you get

Comment: I didn't get error. I want to get only the attribute values, but it gives me the attribute name with the tag name. <meta name="keywords" content="football,cricket,Rugby,Volleyball">

Comment: `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/meta[@name='keywords']")?.Attributes["content"]?.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTML Agility Pack you can use `doc.SelectSingleNode("/html/head/meta[@name = 'keywords']").Attributes["content"].Value`. I think their XPath support for attribute nodes is a bit odd so it is better to select the element and then use the `Attributes` property to select the attribute and the `Value` property to extract the value. If you want to use pure XPath to get the attribute value as a string then use `doc.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("string(/html/head/meta[@name = 'keywords']/@content)")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string() to get just the value:

```
string(//head/meta[@name]/@content/text())
```